# Cannot resolve symbol Toolkit in Java in android

Tags: java, audio, toolkit, beep

I just want some simple code to make a beep when I use it in Java in Android, but when I tried to import the `Toolkit` class in Android Studio, it says that it cannot resolve the symbol. Why is that, and how can I fix this? If I can't use this, is there anything else that's really short and simple that I can use?

```
import java.awt.Toolkit; <---cannot resolve symbol Toolkit

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); <---cannot resolve symbol Toolkit
```

Answer (score 1):

java.awt.* doesn't work on Android. But you can use [ToneGenerator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator):

```
try {
    if (tGen == null) {
        tGen = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
    }         
    tGen.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_BEEP2, 150);

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (tGen != null) {
                tGen.release();
                tGen = null;
            }
        }
    }, 150);
} catch (Exception e) {
    android.util.Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't play sound:" + e.getMessage());
}
```

There are other tones besides [TONE_PROP_BEEP2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ToneGenerator) and 100 is the volume and 150 the duration in millis.

Comment: Can you explain what the 100 and 150 is for?

Comment: Hmmm. It gave me a couple errors when I tried to run the code: java.lang.RuntimeException: Init failed
        at android.media.ToneGenerator.native_setup(Native Method)
        at android.media.ToneGenerator.<init>(ToneGenerator.java:746)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$1.onFinish(MainActivity.java:143)

Comment: this seems to happen if it's not released, I've added a handler to release it.

Comment: This gave the error variable tgen is access from inner class, needs to be declared final. And if you declare it final, it won't let you set tgen = null.

Comment: Try declaring `public ToneGenerator tGen;` in your activity / fragment class

Comment: Did it, ran it, and it gave the same errors in the logcat: 01-10 18:09:55.209 12570-12570/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 12570
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Init failed
        at android.media.ToneGenerator.native_setup(Native Method)

Comment: Ok, this catches the exception and the app doesn't crash anymore. But it's still not playing any sounds, and there's some new errors in the logcat:

Comment: 01-10 18:19:14.300 1152-1522/? E/AudioMixer: AudioMixer::getTrackName out of available tracks
01-10 18:19:14.300 1152-1522/? E/AudioFlinger: no more track names available
01-10 18:19:14.300 1152-1522/? E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
01-10 18:19:14.300 12819-12819/com.example.myapplication E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
01-10 18:19:14.301 12819-12819/com.example.myapplication E/ToneGenerator: AudioTrack->initCheck failed
01-10 18:19:14.301 12819-12819/com.example.myapplication E/ToneGenerator: ToneGenerator init faile

Comment: I've created a repo with the code working as it was in the answer. You can check it in this gitlab repo: https://gitlab.com/jeprubio/android-tone Hope it helps.